# Processing used in scheduled powershell scripts

Tags: powershell

I want a powershell script to run hourly.  Am I best to run the script all day at startup and use sleep to run the code hourly or am I best to use a Windows scheduled task to execute and then close the script?

Which is better for not slowing the PC down?

Comment: None of them will slow the pc down, but I'd recommend using scheduled tasks. Then you won't have to worry about anyone closing the process or if it crashes

Comment: Garbage collection is pretty good in Powershell but running all day means that you will have the potential to waste memory depending on what the script is doing.

Comment: Thank you, the scheduled task for the reasons given by @FrodeF. sounds like the best option.

Comment: Just for completeness I will mention that you could also use PowerShell scheduled jobs for this. There is a pretty good Hey, Scripting Guy blog post [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/12/introduction-to-powershell-scheduled-jobs) to get you started.